# Query table without returning ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Basically I have an app that have a Projects table, and a project belongs to a Client (and the client has a column in the table for it's location).

I've created a search feature where the idea is you search for the project by location then client. I was hoping to use JavaScript to filter out any clients that weren't from the selected locations. I followed a tutorial to do this, however the tutorial assumed that the client belonged to a location, and therefore I'm the below code doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to basically say *'If Client.location = one of the selected locations, show it'*

```
clients = $('#search_client').html()
$('#search_location').change ->
    location = $('#search_location :selected').map(() ->
        return $(this).text();
    ).get().join().split(',');
    console.log(location)
    options_array = []
    for l in location
        options_array.push $(clients).filter('optgroup[label="'+l+'"]').html()
    if options_array
        $('#search_client').html(options_array.join(''))
    else
        $('#search_client').empty()
```

Comment: Link tutorial. You really can do this with just rails if you wanted by creating a scope that excluded the clients not from the queried location.

Comment: I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1zZ4Lgzf9s
I could, I'm very new to rails and programming in general, and I haven't been able to wrap my head around scope for say querying Projects table that relates to a client table, then the client relates to a location table, so I need to query based Projects based on if it's client is in a specified location and so on,